# Xcode Build Error while building iOS Azure Storage Client Library

Tags: xcode, build, azure-mobile-services, azure-blob-storage

I'm attempting to include Azure Blob Storage in an iOS app.

I've been following the step-by-step instructions found in Microsoft's [How to use Azure Blob storage from iOS](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/storage-ios-how-to-use-blob-storage/) web page.

In order to use the service, the iOS framework must be built from the following [Git Repo](https://github.com/Azure/azure-storage-ios) and then linked into the Xcode project that references it.

As instructed in the repo's readme , I have cloned the repo, opened the lib's xcodeproj, built the project using the Azure Storage Client Library target. However, when I subsequently try to build it under the framework target, I get the following error:

> /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/lipo: can't open input file: /Users/luke/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Azure_Storage_Client_Library-dxalmaucvgpwcwgwvbkpvqdydxic/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/libAzure Storage Client Library.a (No such file or directory)

I have tried building against a generic iOS device and various simulators and I always get the same error.

If I navigate to the path of the file that can't be found, I indeed see that the "[...]/Debug-Iphonesimulator" folder is missing, however, a "[...]/Debug-iphoneos" folder is there.

I've seen other SO posts regarding the lipo tool not being able to open the input file that suggest make changes to the build architectures. I have tried playing with these options as suggested but nothing seems to help. Furthermore, I don't understand why this would have to be changed anyway; wouldn't the git project be configured correctly to start with?

Answer (score 1):

A number of people are having this problem (see [this GitHub Issue](https://github.com/Azure/azure-storage-ios/issues/13)).  Unfortunately, we're having trouble repro'ing locally - my guess is that there's a bug in the pbxproj file that only shows up if you're trying to build on a clean machine.  While we work on fixing the problem, can you try [the Cocoapod](https://cocoapods.org/pods/AZSClient) instead, will that work for you?